# MVVM WPF Command not firing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command, prism

I have `MVVM WPF` application. I create `Menu` via a separate service and set to load time.

My shell view which contains the menu is as follows:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MainToolbar" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainToolBarRegion}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,1,1,1" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.133,-5.917" Height="28" >
    <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>

    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="28" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu}" Width="400">
        <Menu.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ThemeMenuItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource KV_MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Text}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80"/>
            </Style>
        </Menu.Resources>
    </Menu>
</ItemsControl>
```

`MenuItem` has a view model behind:

```
    public class MenuItemViewModel : NotificationObject
    {

        private string text;
        private ICommand command;
        private IList<MenuItemViewModel> menuItems;

        public MenuItemViewModel()
        {
            this.menuItems = new List<MenuItemViewModel>();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }
            set
            {
                if (text != value)
                {
                    text = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Text);
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                return command;
            }
            set
            {
                if (command != value)
                {
                    command = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Command);
                }
            }
        }

        public IList<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems
        {
            get { return menuItems; }
            set
            {
                if (menuItems != value)
                {
                    menuItems = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.MenuItems);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Relay command:

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

In menu  service, I assign the command object like follows:

```
...
            MenuItemViewModel app = new MenuItemViewModel();
            app.Text = "APP";
            app.Command = new RelayCommand(
                param => this.App(""),
                        param => true);

            MenuItemViewModel exit = new MenuItemViewModel();
            exit.Text = "Exit";
            exit.Command = new RelayCommand(
                        param => this.Exit(""),
                        param => this.CanExit
                        );
            app.MenuItems.Add(exit);
            mService.AddMenu(app);
...
```

My `MenuItem` is loading fine with assigned header text, but when I click a menu item it is not firing the relevant delegate methods such **App("") or Exit("")**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the this.CanExit property? I sat down yesterday with the same problem, and found out the bug was in the conditional CanExecute method.

Comment: it just return true always.

Comment: As I can't understand your code (e. g. this.App("")), I would recommend to remove all [DebuggerStepThrough] attributes and put breakpoints everywhere, including the CanExecute lines, and just look at what's going on. If nothing happens, call the Command.CanExecute and the Command.Execute in code yourself and see if it fires. I bet you find the error on the way.

Comment: What about your output window? do you see any binding errors?

Comment: @Alan I dont find any binding errors. Applications builds fine

Comment: @kbird Just to make sure, you know I mean the "output" window during runtime when you load your view, not at compile time right

Comment: @Alan ye i dont see any binding errors in runtime. but I can see that the issue is somehow the command is not getting bound to menu item. Somewhere the the syntax is wrong

Comment: Try binding to a DelegateCommand instead new DelegateCommand(()=>this.App(""), ()=> true); to see if it works. You shouldn't need the RelayCommand to prove your XAML bindings etc. work.

Comment: check your bindings at runtime with snoop to see wether the right datacontext is set. its always one of the two - datacontext or binding path :)

Comment: @blindmeis thanks for letting me know about snoop. very useful

Comment: What happened with this? I am having the same issue...